# Why is my significant model giving me a low AUC and ROC?

Tags: r, logistic, cross-validation, unbalanced-classes

For some reason my model keeps showing up to be a poor model when checking its accuracy through the [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) and [AUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Further_interpretations) [ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). This is the model I am stuck with after doing backward elimination. This is the logistic output:

```
`Call:
glm(formula = DEATH_EVENT ~ age + ejection_fraction + serum_sodium +
    time, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = train, control = list(trace = TRUE))

Deviance Residuals:
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
-2.1760  -0.6161  -0.2273   0.4941   2.6827

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)       15.741338   7.534348   2.089  0.03668 *
age                0.063767   0.018533   3.441  0.00058 ***
ejection_fraction -0.080520   0.019690  -4.089 4.33e-05 ***
serum_sodium      -0.111499   0.053639  -2.079  0.03765 *
time              -0.020543   0.003331  -6.167 6.95e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1`
```

This is the confusion matrix output

```
glm.pred Survived Dead
   0       46   10
   1        5   14
```

The auc is showing up as 0.178

```
library(pROC)

# Calculate predicted probabilities for test set
glm.probs <- predict(glm9, newdata=test, type="response")

# Create prediction object for test set
pred <- prediction(glm.probs, test$DEATH_EVENT)

# Create ROC curve for test set
roc.perf <- performance(pred, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")

# Plot ROC curve for test set
plot(roc.perf, legacy.axes = TRUE, percent = TRUE,
     xlab = "False Positive Percentage", ylab = "True Positive Percentage",
     col = "#3182bd", lwd = 4, print.auc = TRUE)

# Add AUC to ROC curve
auc <- as.numeric(performance(pred, measure = "auc")@y.values)
text(x = 0.5, y = 0.3, labels = paste0("AUC = ", round(auc, 3)),
     col = "black", cex = 1.5)
abline(a=0, b= 1)
```

How can I get past this problem?

I check the classes and its showed that there is a data imbalance. But I don’t know what to do with this knowledge.

Comment: Any auc less than 0.5 suggests that there is a problem with how the question was posed. 0.5 is the null hypothesis of no difference. So values far away (on a scale of 0-1) from 0.5 should be considered meaningful. You are just interpreting your results incorrectly. Since the problem has not been defined there’s not a lot more to say.

Comment: Data imbalance? Yeah. An intercept of 15 does imply a huge data imbalance.

Comment: I just checked and it is data imbalance. Any idea how i can fix that :(

Comment: Is this $AUC$ calculated on holdout/test data, or do you get $AUC=0.178$ on in-sample data?

Comment: @rua there are many questions on this site and https://datascience.stackexchange.com about that topic. Sometimes there are different algorithms you can apply (regularization, resampling procedures), but other times you need to change your expectations of performance and/or what criteria you use to evaluate the model (e.g. proper scoring rules).

Answer (score 2):

The performance of a model in terms of AUC relates to the effect size and not to how significant you measured that effect size.

Below is a simpler case as an example for two populations where some feature follows a normal distribution. We can determine that the distributions have significantly different means with a t-test, if we have a sufficient large sample. But a classification using that feature may not need to perform well because the effect size is small.

[image: example]

```
### simulate two populations
### with different means
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(10^4,0.2,1)
y = rnorm(10^4,0,1)

### view of the two distributions 
plot(density(x), main = "density of x and y")
lines(density(y),col=2)
legend(-4,0.4,c("mean = 0.2","mean = 0"), col = c(1,2), lty = 1)

### t-test will be significant 
t.test(x,y)

### create an ROC plot
### a classification can be based on whether the value is above or below some cutoff
cutoff = seq(-4,4,0.01)
p1 = sapply(cutoff, FUN = function(t) {mean(x<t)})
p2 = sapply(cutoff, FUN = function(t) {mean(y<t)})
plot(p1,p2, type = "l", xlab = "P(X < cutoff)\n false positive", ylab = "P(Y < cutoff)\n true positive", main = "a not so great ROC curve")
```

> The auc is showing up as 0.178

This indicates some bigger problem. I can't easily verify your code without the data.

One possibility is that you invert the labels positive/negative (as I did in the first version of the answer) then the computed area will be one minus the true AUC and can get below 0.5

Another possibility is that the model is overfitting on the training data and performs badly with AUC<0.5 on tests data. (although the output from you GLM doesn't look like overfitting)